# Scrape web content that was generated by JavaScript to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I was scraping some web content using VBA and MSXML, so I know the basics. But now I would like to get data from web page which was generated by JavaScript.
I can't give you exact link because it's private, but I can describe it - basically, there is div container with headings and some images, and below it is tables, which load dynamically (rounding circles), but not updating (so they load only once). If open source code view in browser, you can't find these tables, only container and headings/src of images. But if you click on tables and choose "inspect element", you are able to see typical structure of `<th <tr> <td>` etc.
Methods I know:

1) Save page and then scrape it - probably not the best solution.

Is there any fast way to save all pages if I have a list of their URLs?

2) Use Internet Explorer controls via VBA, wait till page is loaded and then get elements as usual - but seems slow for me(?) - like 25s on one page, even if it's loaded for 0.5s.

Maybe I should turn off something that slows down loading?
Can you check what is wrong?

Here is code I found:

```
Sub FuturesScrap3(ByVal URL As String)

Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim AnchorLinks As Object
Dim tdElements As Object
Dim tdElement As Object
Dim AnchorLink As Object
Dim lRow As Long
Dim oElement As Object

Dim oIE As InternetExplorer

Set oIE = New InternetExplorer

oIE.navigate URL
oIE.Visible = True

Do Until (oIE.readyState = 4 And Not oIE.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

'Wait for Javascript to run
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oIE.document.body.innerHTML

With HTMLDoc.body
    Set AnchorLinks = .getElementsByTagName("a")
    Set tdElements = .getElementsByTagName("td") '

    For Each AnchorLink In AnchorLinks
        Debug.Print AnchorLink.innerText
    Next AnchorLink

End With

lRow = 1
For Each tdElement In tdElements
    Debug.Print tdElement.innerText
    Cells(lRow, 1).Value = tdElement.innerText
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next

'Clicking the Month tab
For Each oElement In oIE.document.all
    If Trim(oElement.innerText) = "Month" Then
        oElement.Focus
        oElement.Click
    End If
Next oElement

Do Until (oIE.readyState = 4 And Not oIE.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

'Wait for Javascript to run
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oIE.document.body.innerHTML

With HTMLDoc.body
    Set AnchorLinks = .getElementsByTagName("a")
    Set tdElements = .getElementsByTagName("td") '

    For Each AnchorLink In AnchorLinks
        Debug.Print AnchorLink.innerText
    Next AnchorLink
End With

lRow = 1
For Each tdElement In tdElements
    Debug.Print tdElement.innerText
    Cells(lRow, 2).Value = tdElement.innerText
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next tdElement End sub
```

3) Use web drivers like Selenium - couldn't find proper examples. If you give me some from scratch, like getting data from element by classname, it will be great.

4) Unknown for me, but possibly the fastest - getting data directly from JS variables/arrays which are used to build these tables. I heard you can connect VBA with JavaScript but haven't found any proper examples how to get data.

All solutions should be in VBA range. I would like to know what is the fastest way.

Comment: Can you just use Excel's built in Web Data retrieval?

Comment: If your code is working and youre looking for improvements consider asking the question at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments.
@Marc, no, it was not possible to get the data using web query/power query's "import from web", only headings.

I edited code a bit - there was 1 minute(!) delay (maybe author made mistake when he added delay to load scripts on page).

```
Sub FuturesScrap3(ByVal URL As String)

Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim AnchorLinks As Object
Dim tdElements As Object
Dim tdElement As Object
Dim AnchorLink As Object
Dim lRow As Long
Dim oElement As Object

Dim oIE As InternetExplorer

Set oIE = New InternetExplorer

oIE.navigate URL
oIE.Visible = True

Do Until (oIE.readyState = 4 And Not oIE.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

'Wait for Javascript to run - 1 second is enough in my case
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oIE.document.body.innerHTML

With HTMLDoc.body
    Set AnchorLinks = .getElementsByTagName("a")
    Set tdElements = .getElementsByTagName("td") '

    For Each AnchorLink In AnchorLinks
        Debug.Print AnchorLink.innerText
    Next AnchorLink

End With

lRow = 1
For Each tdElement In tdElements
    Debug.Print tdElement.innerText
    Cells(lRow, 1).Value = tdElement.innerText
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next

'Clicking the Month tab
For Each oElement In oIE.document.all
    If Trim(oElement.innerText) = "Month" Then
        oElement.Focus
        oElement.Click
    End If
Next oElement

Do Until (oIE.readyState = 4 And Not oIE.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop


HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oIE.document.body.innerHTML

With HTMLDoc.body
    Set AnchorLinks = .getElementsByTagName("a")
    Set tdElements = .getElementsByTagName("td") '

    For Each AnchorLink In AnchorLinks
        Debug.Print AnchorLink.innerText
    Next AnchorLink
End With

lRow = 1
For Each tdElement In tdElements
    Debug.Print tdElement.innerText
    Cells(lRow, 2).Value = tdElement.innerText
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next tdElement 
End sub
```